# How to add TreeMap and Pie Chart as Subplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, pie-chart, treemap

I am trying to add a PIE chart and Treemap as a subplot. 
Like below(Expected) :-
[image]

As per [squarify documentation](https://github.com/laserson/squarify/blob/master/squarify/__init__.py), **I was trying to pass axis object as ax parameter**. However its not working. On passing axis object, the second plot is coming as empty.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import squarify
# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 10, dt)
nse = np.random.randn(len(t))
r = np.exp(-t / 0.05)

cnse = np.convolve(nse, r) * dt
cnse = cnse[:len(t)]
s = 0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t) + cnse

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, constrained_layout=True)
fig.set_figheight(7)
fig.set_figwidth(13)
#plt.subplot(211)


# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs']
sizes = [15, 30]
explode = (0, 0.1)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')


ax0.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
#plt.subplot(212)
#ax1.psd(s, 512, 1 / dt)

plt.show()



volume = [350, 220, 170, 150, 50]
labels = ['Liquid\n volume: 350k', 'Savoury\n volume: 220k', 'Sugar\n volume: 170k',
          'Frozen\n volume: 150k', 'Non-food\n volume: 50k']
color_list = ['#0f7216', '#b2790c', '#ffe9a3', '#f9d4d4', '#d35158', '#ea3033']

plt.rc('font', size=14)
squarify.plot(sizes=volume, label=labels,
              color=color_list, alpha=0.7)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```

Comment: When you execute `plt.show()`, matplotlib shows the plot and immediately when the plot is closed it is erased. So, you'll probably want to remove the first call to `plt.plot` . Also, you probably want to add `ax=ax1` in the call to `squarify.plot(..., ax=ax1)`

Comment: @JohanC You were right. plt.show() was the issue. Also thanks for enhancing my knowledge from the fact I was unaware about show();

Comment: Actually before posting only I added. But as you rightly pointed show() method was the culprit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Above code was almost correct expect 1 issue. Before Squerify's plot there was an statement to call show method. After Removing its working. 
Credit : @JahanC

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.mlab as mlab
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import squarify
# Fixing random state for reproducibility
np.random.seed(19680801)

dt = 0.01
t = np.arange(0, 10, dt)
nse = np.random.randn(len(t))
r = np.exp(-t / 0.05)

cnse = np.convolve(nse, r) * dt
cnse = cnse[:len(t)]
s = 0.1 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t) + cnse

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, constrained_layout=True)
fig.set_figheight(7)
fig.set_figwidth(13)
#plt.subplot(211)


# Pie chart, where the slices will be ordered and plotted counter-clockwise:
labels = ['Frogs', 'Hogs']
sizes = [15, 30]
explode = (0, 0.1)  # only "explode" the 2nd slice (i.e. 'Hogs')


ax0.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%',
        shadow=True, startangle=90)
#plt.subplot(212)
#ax1.psd(s, 512, 1 / dt)




volume = [350, 220, 170, 150, 50]
labels = ['Liquid\n volume: 350k', 'Savoury\n volume: 220k', 'Sugar\n volume: 170k',
          'Frozen\n volume: 150k', 'Non-food\n volume: 50k']
color_list = ['#0f7216', '#b2790c', '#ffe9a3', '#f9d4d4', '#d35158', '#ea3033']

plt.rc('font', size=14)
squarify.plot(sizes=volume, label=labels, ax=ax1,
              color=color_list, alpha=0.7)
plt.axis('off')

plt.show()
```